# Find where array values increase monotonically over some value

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to find the locations in an array where the values increase monotonically such that the total change in value is greater than k.
Ie for `k = 5` and `data = [1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 6, 14, 3, 4]`
I would want to return:

```
[4, 7]
```

In general the array would be floats.

**Edit to further clarify:** In the example the data values increase monotonically by greater than 5 in two intervals. The first is from element 0 to 4 (where the data values increase by 9), the 2nd is from element 6 to 7 (where the data values increase by 8). Thus, I want to report the end of each valid interval.

I want to avoid loops and make this efficient. If necessary the range of consecutive values to check could be limited.

Comment: What's the logic behind [4,7]? Could you explain it in a clearer way?

Comment: Made an edit in the clarify section to give a bit more details there. Hope they are coherent with the idea of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
d = a[1:] - a[:-1]
mask = np.concatenate(( [False], d > 0, [False] ))
start = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] > mask[:-1])
stop = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] < mask[:-1])
count = np.bincount(np.repeat(np.arange(start.size) ,stop - start), d[mask[1:-1]])
out = stop[count > k]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [202]: a # Adding in two monotonically decreasing elems at start for variety
Out[202]: array([10,  7,  1,  4,  5,  7, 10,  9,  6, 14,  3,  4])

In [203]: k = 5

In [204]: out
Out[204]: array([6, 9])
```